# Where is QtQuick 2.3?

Tags: qt, qt-quick

I want to learn qt by using the tutorial below

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/gettingstartedqml.html

The tutorial are using QtQuick 2.3 which I dont have. I only have QtQuick 2.2(autogenerated when creating new project). Where do I find this QtQuick 2.3?

Im just starting Qt few days ago which I downloaded the latest version of Qt. I also try to update using MaintenanceTool.exe. I can confirm that i have the latest version.

Im using the free open source version of Qt.

Where do I find this QtQuick 2.3?

Comment: If you have the latest official version of Qt (5.3.1), then you should have QtQuick 2.3.  The template for the new project doesn't look like it's using the latest version.

Comment: im using the online installer. i just updated using MaintenanceTool.exe. How come i did not have the latest version?